# Counting items in list before consecutive instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to count the amount of items in an array before a consecutive amount of zeroes which is inputted by the user.

```
['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E']
```

For example, if the user inputs 3, there are three items in the list before a consecutive amount of three zeroes.

At the moment my code checks for the amount of consecutive zeroes and returns based on that - how can I change this to also gain the value of items before the consecutive instance?

```
LargeBlock = max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(line) if k == '0')
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary? Combined with custom class? What exactly are you asking? You want us to do the work for you?

Comment: Could you at least outline what you think is the problem with the code you already have? Errors (provide traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Do we get a stake in the venture for answering?

Comment: @devnull I'm trying to become more confident with Python by completing tasks. I've tried searching for a solution for the past few days and have come up with nothing. I'd like an idea of what I can do so I can look it up and try to create a solution to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seats, wanted = ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E'], 3
from itertools import groupby
for occ, grp in groupby(enumerate(seats[:-1], 1), key = lambda x: x[1]):
    if occ == '0':
        available = list(grp)
        if len(available) >= wanted:
            print([seats[-1] + str(item[0]) for item in available[:wanted]])

# ['E4', 'E5', 'E6']
```

Comment: Better to use `sum(1 for _ in grp)` rather than converting to a list.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik The indexes are still in the group only, so I had to convert to a list.

Answer (score 5):

This is *much* easier if you first convert the list to string:

```
  row = ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E']
  seats = ''.join(row[:-1])
```

Once in string form, it is easy to search for a block of seats:

```
  block = '0' * n
  location = s.find(block)
```

Here is all the code in a single function:

```
def search(available, required):
    'Return the first available block of seats on a given row'
    row = available[-1]
    seats = ''.join(available[:-1])
    block = '0' * required
    i = seats.find(block)
    if i == -1:
        raise ValueError('no block large enough')
    return '%s%d-%s%d' % (row, i+1, row, i+required)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print search(['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E'], required=3)
```

If you want to stick with your original *itertools.groupby* approach, then you need to track both the position and values as you loop.  This is a job for [*enumerate()*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> def is_occupied(t):
        seat, occupied = t
        return occupied

>>> def seat_number(t):
        seat, occupied = t
        return seat

>>> required = 3
>>> row = ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E']
>>> for occupied, groups in groupby(enumerate(row[:-1]), key=is_occupied):
        if occupied == '0':
            seats = list(map(seat_number, groups))
            if len(seats) >= required:
                print(seats[:required])
```

Eventhough *groupby()* can be made to work for you, it is tricky to use with a stream of tuples (such as that generated by *enumerate()*).  If you're aiming for clarity, it is something better to skip the functional programming composition tricks and just look normally.

Here is a straight-forward, non-functional approach:

```
>>> cumulative_open = 0
>>> row_letter = row[-1]

>>> row = ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'E']
>>> required = 3

>>> row_letter = row[-1]
>>> cumulative_open = 0
>>> for i, occupied in enumerate(row[:-1], 1):
        if occupied == "1":
            cumulative_open = 0
            continue
        cumulative_open += 1
        if cumulative_open >= required:
            print('%s%d-%s%d' % (row_letter, i-required+1, row_letter, i))
            break
else:
    print("Not enough open seats")


E4-E6
```

Comment: +1.. Python is elegant because of the core pythonistas' elegance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.... A very basic Theatre/Row manager.

```
class Row():

    class SeatOccupiedException(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, seats):
        """
        Create a theatre row with seats.

        seats ::= number of seats in the row
        """
        self.seats = [False]*seats

    def get_seats(self, group_size=1, empty=True):
        """
        Get seats from the row in chunks according to group size.
        Can get empty or non-empty seats.

        group_size ::= amount of seats needed.
        empty      ::= should the seats be empty or not?
        """
        ret = []
        current_seats = []

        for idx, seat in enumerate(self.seats, 1):
            if seat != empty:
                current_seats.append(idx)
            if len(current_seats) >= group_size:
                ret.append(current_seats[-group_size:])

        return ret

    def occupy_seats(self, seats):
        """
        Occupy some seats
        """
        for seat in seats:
            if self.seats[seat]:
                raise SeatOccupiedException()
            self.seats[seat] = True

    def vacate_seats(self, seats):
        """
        Vacate some seats
        """        
        for seat in seats:            
            self.seats[seat] = False

class Theatre():            

    class RowAlreadyExistsException(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, rows=None, seats_per_row=10):
        """
        Create a theatre with rows, each row has seats.

        rows          ::= a list of the names for each row
        seats_per_row ::= number of seats in the row

        Examples:
        t = Theatre(['A', 'B', 'C']) 
        => produces a theatre with 3 rows (A,B,C) with 10 seats
        t = Theatre('ABCDEFG', 3) 
        => produces a theatre with 7 rows (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) with 3 seats
        """        
        self.rows = {}
        if rows:
            for row in rows:
                self.add_row(row, seats_per_row)

    def add_row(self, row_id, seats):
        """
        Add a row to the theatre

        row_id ::= the name of the row
        seats  ::= number of seats in the row
        """
        if row_id in self.rows:
            raise RowAlreadyExistsException()
        self.rows[row_id] = Row(seats)

    def get_available_seats(self, group_size, row_id=None):
        """
        Get all seats available for a group of a certain size
        Can specify a specific row or all of them

        group_size ::= how many available seats are needed
        row_id     ::= specify a certain row if desired
        """
        ret = {}

        def get_row(k):
            ret[k] = self.rows[k].get_seats(group_size)

        rows = [row_id] if row_id else self.rows
        for row_id in self.rows:
            get_row(row_id)

        return ret

    def occupy_seats(self, row_id, seats):
        """
        Occupy some seats
        """           
        self.rows[row_id].occupy_seats(seats)

    def vacate_seats(self, row_id, seats):
        """
        Vacate some seats
        """   
        self.rows[row_id].vacate_seats(seats)
```